# Как убрать лишние нули в дроби (напр. 0,100 = 0,1)?

Tags: php

Полазил по инету - ничего не нашел, в голову лезет только смотреть с последнего симвла и удалять, если он ноль, но ведь наверняка есть более красивый способ?

Comment: Для точки и запятой

         preg_replace('/(\d+[.,]\d+?)0*/', '$1', '0.100');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rtrim('0.100', '0')
```

Comment: Работает только со строкой, представляющее вещественное число. С целым числом, например `100`, выдаст 1.

Answer (score 2):

Если убрать лишние нули нужно на выводе, то используйте функцию printf() и sprintf() Например:

```
$money = 12.12345;
$format = sprintf("%01.2f", $money);
echo $format;
```

Выведет на экран только 12.12

Comment: Также стоит добавить что число округлится до заданной точности.

`sprintf("%.2f", 12.12945);`
выведет: 12.13

Answer (score 1):

ну да, в этом случае лучше всего rtrim('0.100','0');
ибо явно подразумевается вывод куда-то.

Comment: Отлично, мужики. Большое спасибо :)
Единственное, если в базе целое число, то выводится, например "2.", точку обрезаем в случае необходимости так:
rtrim(rtrim($res->fields['z_phaze'], '0'), '.');

Comment: Можно одной функцией:

    rtrim('2.00', '0.'); // 2

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, работает только со строкой, представляющей вещественное число в интервале (-10; 10). С числом, например, `100.00`, выдаст `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Эм.
Что-то други мои вы надумываете великие велосипеды, есть же готовое решение [round()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
$val=0.100;
$new_value=round($val,1);
echo $new_value; // выведет 0,1
```

Зачем изобретать

> в голову лезет только смотреть с
> моследнего симвла и удалять, если он
> ноль

Это же просто ппц.

Comment: :D
Оно и без round веведет 0.1 ;)
если уж на то пошло.

Comment: Ну вывести выведет \+ округлит. но циклом бежать по числу ИМХО бред.

Comment: @Shrek А в `round($val,1)` число 1 откуда взялось?

Comment: @alexlz

>0,100 = 0,1

в вопросе стоит до 1 символа после точки. Так понятнее?

А вообще я сам его написал. А кто до меня придумал цифру 1 не знаю, даже и не интересно, но пользуюсь ею :)

Comment: @Shrek Да я про то, что теперь надо ждать вопроса, как убрать лишние нули в хвосте "0,120".

Comment: Ахахахахахахаха

Answer (score 1):

во первых, работа round выдаст идентичный результат sprintf.

во вторых проблемы нету:

```
$val=0.100; echo $val;
```

выведет: 0.1

C другой стороны если мы зададим число как строку:

```
$val="0.100"; echo $val;
```

выведет: 0.100

Поэтому мы преобразуем строку в число и выйдет то что нам нужно:

```
$val="0.100"; echo (float)$val;
```

выедет: 0.1

Comment: Зачем задавать число строкой?

Comment: Ну я только этим могу объяснить эту задачу. что число задается строкой / вырезается откуда то / ... / но в итоге получается строка. Иначе вопроса не было бы

Answer (score 0):

(float) при очень маленьких числах даст E нотацию. типа: 4.343434E-5

Answer (score 0):

Умножить на 1

```
$val=0.100;
$val=$val*1;
echo $val; // 0.1
```